# Ubuntu 20.04.1 randomly freezes on MSI GF75

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, freeze, crash, msi

I'm experiencing random freezes while using my Ubuntu installation in a MSI GF75 computer, with Windows 10 in dual boot. This kind of freezes avoids me to use any key or the mouse, and stops the sound, forcing me to hard reboot my computer, since it doesn't unfreeze after a long period of time. There isn't likely a pattern for this to occur, since I was doing different things in different freezes. I tried to check the output of

```
journalctl  -b -1 -xe
```

just after rebooting, but I don't find anything suspicious. The computer comes with a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, which I think has the latest drivers since I used

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

to keep them updated. Also, it doesn't seem to be a problem with temperature, since `sensors` always give me a temperature below 40 celsius, and this problem doesn't happen in Windows (which is more exigent), which makes me think that is a software problem related with Ubuntu. By the same reason, I don't think that is a problem with the RAM memory or with SWAP, but I could be wrong. If you need the output of any command let me know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: what drivers are you using for the Nvidia card? Is it `nouveau` or the proprietary version?

Comment: you can check in software & updates > Additional drivers

Comment: @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne exactly I'm using  the NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-455, propietary version.

Comment: don't hard reboot or it might corrupt data. Press the SysRq key (usually PrtScn) together with REISUB in turn. Refer to (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will have it in mind when my computer freezes again.

Comment: I have identical problem on Linux Mint 20.3 Una base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal.
Laptop msi gf75 thin 10scxr(GTX 1650)
On Windows 10 no problems.
I changed memory, I used other ubuntu from usb ssd and also have random freezes. I used different drivers(470, 510,515,520, 520-open). It is not helped.
I think it is problem in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible cause for this bug:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/bug-report-455-23-04-kernel-panic-due-to-null-pointer-dereference/155506

Possibly fixed by driver 460.56. I have not had the chance to try it yet (I'm still at 460.39 with Ubuntu 20.04, RTX 3070), and I get random freezes too.

Edit: driver updates did not help me. Eventually I found that using Ubuntu LTS enablement (also called HWE or Hardware Enablement) fixes the freezes I had. I'm guessing the LTS kernel was not compatible with my intel CPU, even though it's not that new.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the reason of random freezes. I'll try it and see if it works. Thank you for the information.